# Transaction too large or lock too many accouns on RPC level

Tags: transactions, rpc, versionedtransactions

I have a scenario where I have my program ix + a 3rd party (Jupyter swap) tx decompiled to ixtructions + another of my instruction, bundled in a single transaction. On my end just before calling the RPC `client.send_transaction(&tx).await` I check the number of accounts I send, by iterating over all instructions and adding all the accounts in a set, and they are like 55-60 so no more than 64 accounts, and I get `Transaction simulation failed: Transaction locked too many accounts`, so it looks like something happens at the RPC level such as the tx contains more accounts than what we sent.
Also sometimes I get an error that the transaction size is too big, but I check just before sending the transaction the size of the encoded versioned transaction and it fits in the limit.
How can I reliably check on my side what's happening so I can know before sending the transaction if I lock too many accounts or the transaction is too big?

Comment: Double check that your instruction does not have more than 64 accounts as the situation where *"at the RPC level the tx contains more accounts than what we sent"* is not possible since adding accounts to a tx invalidates the sender's signature.

Be aware that the list of accounts includes system accounts, signer's account etc.

Comment: Additionally, if you're using Jupiter, there's a good chance that they're using an address-lookup-table in the transaction, which allows a transaction to load more accounts. Including those, the transaction is likely going over the limit.